# Error while installing Qiskit version 0.22.0

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am getting following error  while I write:

```
pip3 install qiskit==0.22.0
```

in the terminal.

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for qiskit-aer
  Building wheel for qiskit-terra (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for qiskit-terra (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [814 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/qiskit
```

.
.
.

```
 error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qiskit-terra
Failed to build qiskit-aer qiskit-terra
ERROR: Could not build wheels for qiskit-terra, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're trying to install qiskit-terra==0.22.0. The current version of qiskit-terra is 0.23.1, while the current version of the base qiskit package (that is trying to be installed from your command) is 0.41.0.

To install qiskit-terra 0.22.0 you want to `pip install qiskit==0.39.0`, see https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/releases/tag/0.39.0.

Base qiskit 0.22.0 dates back to Oct 5, 2020, which is likely to cause errors with python.